# Refresh child in dynamically created nested accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

I am trying to append items to a nested accordion dynamically when the user clicks a button. I am using the following code to create a nested accordion:

```
  $(".accordion").accordion({
  collapsible: true, 
  autoHeight: false, 
  animated: 'swing',
  heightStyle: "content",
  changestart: function(event, ui) {
      child.accordion("activate", false);
  }
});

var child = $(".child-accordion").accordion({
  active:false,
  collapsible: true, 
  autoHeight: false,
  animated: 'swing'
});
```

In order to do this, I have found that I need to refresh the accordion using the following:

```
$('.accordion').accordion("refresh");
```

My problem is that when I try to refresh the inner accordion using:

```
$('.child-accordion').accordion("refresh");
```

I get the following: 
    Error: cannot call methods on accordion prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'refresh'

When I inspect the div that should be refreshed it has the following ids/classes:

```
DIV#shelf0sections.child-accordion.ui-accordion-content.ui-helper-reset.ui-...
```

I tried using the selector:

```
$('#shelf0sections .child-accordion').accordion("refresh");
```

instead which doesn't give an error, but nothing happens visually.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Mw9SA/3/
(Note that the first element in the list is just an example to see the nested accordion working, If you try to add sections to it, it won't work. Use the '+Shelf' button, then open the new accordion and use the '+Section' button.)

Comment: Hey @b-en, where in the code are you trying to call ```$('.child-accordion').accordion("refresh");``` maybe a quick check would be see if that ```refresh``` call isnt being made before ```var child = $(".child-accordion").accordion({...});``` bit?

Comment: Hi @Varinder, I am confident that the element exists before I am trying to refresh it. For example if I type into the console once the element has been created I still get
    into$('.child-accordion').accordion("refresh");
    20:23:01.853 Error: cannot call methods on accordion prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'refresh'
Whereas if I call the following, it works correctly:
    20:23:06.048 $('.child-accordion').fadeOut("slow");

Comment: Would it be possible to post a quick fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/ ?

Comment: Here: http://jsfiddle.net/Mw9SA/3/, thanks for taking a look.

Comment: Also note that the first element in the list is just an example to see the nested accordion working, If you try to add sections to it, it won't work.

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'sections' of undefined`

Comment: @wiz kid, is that trying to add a section to the default element? I just had that as an example of the nested accordions working. The '+ Section button' will only work to add sections to a newly added shelf (use the '+ Shelf' then '+ Section' buttons).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about a more modular approach?

Fiddle or it didnt happen: http://jsfiddle.net/Varinder/24hsd/1/

**Explanation**

The idea is ( the same ) to create a brand new accordion element on the fly with correct events attached and appended somewhere in the DOM.

It's generaly more managable to have repeater `HTML` markup abstracted away in a `template` somewhere in DOM and use JS to reference it rather that building it from a string.

Heres the accordion template in the markup:

```
<div class="template">
    <div class="accordion">
        <h3 class="accordion-title">accordion title</h3>
        <div class="accordion-content">
            accordion content
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Heres the full HTML markup - just in case:

```
<div class="page">
</div>

<div id="addShelf" class="button">+ Shelf</div>
<div id="addSection" class="button">+ Section</div>

<div class="template">
    <div class="accordion">
        <h3 class="accordion-title">accordion title</h3>
        <div class="accordion-content">
            accordion content
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

Starting off by storing different accordion configurations:

```
var shelfConfig = {
    collapsible: true, 
    autoHeight: false, 
    animated: "swing",
    heightStyle: "content"
}

var shelfSectionConfig = {
    active:false,
    collapsible: true, 
    autoHeight: false,
    animated: "swing"
}
```

Kepping a track of current accordion number and current accordion section number ( number of sections inside last accordion ) - might come in handy if you require a feature to remove an accordion shelf

```
var currentShelfNumber = 0;
var currentShelfSectionNumber = 0;
```

Chaching DOM elements, notice reference to the `tempalte` div

```
var $page = $(".page");
var $accordionTemplate = $(".template").children();

var $addSection = $("#addSection");
var $addShelf = $("#addShelf");
```

Creating a helper function that simply returns a cloned copy of the accordion template from the DOM

```
function getAccordionTemplate() {
     return $accordionTemplate.clone();   
}
```

Main function `generateAccordion` - it takes two arguments, `accordionNumber` to append current number in titles etc and `accordionType` to find out which accordion configuration to use.

With those parameters it will return a brand-spanking-new accordion with appropriate events attached which can then be append to the DOM

```
function generateAccordion( number, accordionType ) {
    var $accordion = getAccordionTemplate();
    var accordionTitle = "twerking bieber?";

    if ( accordionType == "shelf" ) {
        accordionTitle = "Shelf " + number;    
    } else {
         accordionTitle = "Shelf Section";
    }

    $accordion.find("h3").text( accordionTitle );

    var $accordionWithEvents = attachAccordionEvents( $accordion, accordionType );

    return $accordionWithEvents;
}
```

Notice the call to another function `attachAccordionEvents` as the name suggests - this fella will attach events to the accordion element.

```
function attachAccordionEvents( $accordionElement, accordionType ) {
    if ( accordionType == "shelf" ) {
        $accordionElement.accordion( shelfConfig );
    } else {
        $accordionElement.accordion( shelfSectionConfig );    
    }

    return $accordionElement;
}
```

Another helper function which makes sure "add section" button doesnt show up if there is no accordion shelf for it to work on

```
function manageSectionButton() {
    if ( $page.children().length > 0 ) {
        $addSection.show();
    } else {
        $addSection.hide();
    }
}
```

Finaly events and logic:

```
$addShelf.on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var newShelfNumber = currentShelfNumber + 1;
    var $shelfElement = generateAccordion( newShelfNumber, "shelf" );

    currentShelfNumber = newShelfNumber;

    $page.append( $shelfElement );


    manageSectionButton();
});

$addSection.on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var newShelfSectionNumber = currentShelfSectionNumber + 1;
    var $shelfSectionElement = generateAccordion( newShelfSectionNumber, "section" );
    var $activeShelfElement = $page.children().last().find(".accordion-content");

    $activeShelfElement.append( $shelfSectionElement );
});
```

... And thats about it.

Hope this helps,

Cheers

Comment: Wow, this is amazing! Thank you so much for your help. As you can probably tell, I am new to web development so I really appreciate the thorough answer and explanation! I'll report back once I refactor my code. Thank you again!

Comment: I went through my code and ended up using a lot of what you suggested. The only difference was that I wanted all of the elements to belong to the same accordion so that I could use .accordion("option", "active") as well as force only one to be open at a time. To accomplish this I removed the outer div from the template, so that just the accordion h3 & div get applied. Thanks again, you really helped me out and my code makes a lot more sense now.